# Has PowerShell 7.2.12 broken Connect-MgGraph with AccessToken?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

Since upgrading our build agents from PowerShell 7.2.11 to 7.2.12, they have been reporting the following error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'AccessToken'. Cannot convert the *** value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

Our script is as follows:

```bash
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$graphApiToken
)

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphApiToken
```

This was working previously, and rolling back to our previous build agent image has resolved the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a module versioning issues - the Microsoft Graph v1.0 module accepts a string for the access token, but [in v2.0 it only accepts `SecureString` instances](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/microsoft-graph-powershell-v2-is-now-in-public-preview-half-the-size-and-will-speed-up-your-automations/#4-certificate-credentials)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a change in behavior between v1.0 and v2.0 of the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module.

If you want your scripts to maintain compatibility with v1.0, simply convert the access token value conditionally:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$graphApiToken
)

$targetParameter = (Get-Command Connect-MgGraph).Parameters['AccessToken']

if ($targetParameter.ParameterType -eq [securestring]){
  Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken ($graphApiToken |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
}
else {
  Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphApiToken
}
```

Comment: Two things. 1. This is a very clever solution to this problem. 2. This type of problem was on my backlog for a separate issue where I needed to know the expected type for an input variable. So thank you :)